# Stroke containing alternating dashes and dots in OL

Tags: html-lists, openlayers

I'm trying to draw a line around a geometry, my wish is to alternate between dashes and dots as you see in the picture, the issue here is to have them in different colors. [The dot is black while the dash/square is gray](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qg1sb.png)

Any suggestions on how to go about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a style array with two styles, both should have the same `lineDash` with one having an offset of half that interval, for example

```
 [
   new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: 'black',
      lineDash: [0, 30],
      lineDashOffset: 15,
      lineCap: 'round',
    }),
  }),
  new Style({
    stroke: new Stroke({
      width: 6,
      color: 'gray',
      lineDash: [0, 30],
      lineDashOffset: 0,
      lineCap: 'square',
    }),
  }),
];
```